# How can I use AsyncStorage for my textinput?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have a textinput where its written "Search" as a placeholder, and i use android emulator.
What i want to do is, whatever i write in textinput, i want it to hold in memory.

So when i restart the application, it should tell me what i wrote before. For example i write "computer". After I restart and write "com" it should show me if i want to write "computer".

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Application from "../icons/application.svg"
import HorizontalCircles from '../HorizontalCircles';
import HorizontalDiscussion from "../HorizontalDiscussion";
import Energy from "../icons/energy.svg"
import Add from "../icons/add.svg"
import Calendar from "../icons/calendar.svg"
import Clock from "../icons/clock.svg"

const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  

  const inputRef = useRef(); // to make "O" letter in textinput clickable
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    <HorizontalCircles skeleton={true} key={0} colorFirst={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} colorSecond={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"}/>,
    <HorizontalCircles skeleton={true} key={1} colorFirst={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} colorSecond={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"}/>,

  ])

  const [horizontalDiscussion, setHorizontalDiscussion] = useState([
    <HorizontalDiscussion skeleton = {true} key={0} color={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} />,
    <HorizontalDiscussion skeleton = {true} key={1} color={"rgb(" + 100 + "," + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"} />,

  ]); 

  const getUsers = () => {
    // TODO: get discussion from SERVER
    // Dumy Data
    console.log("Getting Users");

    const tmpUsers = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      const rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      const rand2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      const rand3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

      tmpUsers.push(<HorizontalCircles key={i} colorFirst={"rgb(" + rand + "," + rand2 + "," + rand3 + ")"} colorSecond={"rgb(" + rand3 + "," + rand + "," + rand2 + ")"} />)
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUsers(tmpUsers);
    }, 5000);

  }

  const AddNewUser = () => {
    console.log("Adding a New User");

    const tmpUsers = users;

    const rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    const rand2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    const rand3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    //tmpUsers.push(<HorizontalCircles key={tmpUsers.length} colorFirst={"rgb(" + rand + "," + rand2 + "," + rand3 + ")"} colorSecond={"rgb(" + rand3 + "," + rand + "," + rand2 + ")"} />)
    const newUser = <HorizontalCircles key={tmpUsers.length} colorFirst={"rgb(" + rand + "," + rand2 + "," + rand3 + ")"} colorSecond={"rgb(" + rand3 + "," + rand + "," + rand2 + ")"} />

    setUsers(old => [...old, newUser]);
  }

  const getDiscussion = () => {
    // TODO: get discussion from SERVER
    // Dumy Data

    console.log("Getting Discussion Card")
    const tmpHorizontal = [];

    for (let i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
      const rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      const rand2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      const rand3 = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);

      tmpHorizontal.push(<HorizontalDiscussion key={i} color={"rgb(" + rand + "," + rand2 + "," + rand3 + ")"} />)
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setHorizontalDiscussion(tmpHorizontal);
    },3000);

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
    getDiscussion();
  }, [])


  return (
    // for ios, i add safeareview and flex:1, otherwise height doesnt become 100%
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, }} >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.appIcon}>
          <Application height={30} width={22} fill={"#1E2439"} />
          <View style={{ height: 30, width: 30, backgroundColor: "#DBF1F9", borderRadius: 20 }} />
        </View>
        <View style={[styles.input, { flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }]}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => inputRef.current.focus()}>
            <Text style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>O</Text>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          <TextInput style={{ flex: 1 }} placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="#B9B9C5" onChangeText={setText} value={text} ref={inputRef}></TextInput>
        </View>
        <Text>{text}</Text>

        {/* Horizontal Circles */}
        {/* we can set height property for scrollview if want bigger touchable area or
        we can give height for view, and make flex:1 for scrollview */}
        <View>
          <ScrollView snapToInterval={75} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 20, alignItems: "center" }} horizontal={true}>
            
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={AddNewUser}>
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF", borderRadius: 20, marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 20, borderStyle: "dotted", borderWidth: 5, borderColor: "#E2E2E2" }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, color: "#E2E2E2", lineHeight: 30, }}>+</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>           

            {users}
            {/* <HorizontalCircles colorFirst={"#CFC8FF"} colorSecond={"#4CC98F"} />  we made here more effective using useState and useEffect*/}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>

        <ScrollView>
          {/* Discussion Part */}
          <Text style={styles.blackText}>Group Discussion On Going</Text>

          <View style={{ height: 250 }}>
            <ScrollView snapToInterval={Dimensions.get("screen").width - 70} horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", paddingLeft: 20, }}>
              {horizontalDiscussion}
            </ScrollView>
          </View>

          <Text style={styles.blackText}>Todays Task</Text>

          {/* Task Part */}
          <View style={{ padding: 30 }}>
            <View style={styles.task}>
              <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEFE2", padding: 10, borderRadius: 13 }}>
                <Energy height={35} width={25} fill={"#FB9238"} />
              </View>

              <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.blackTextInside}>8 Tasks Today</Text>
                <Text style={styles.grayText}>Meet them & Share your experience</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
                <Add height={35} width={25} fill={"#ABA8BA"} />

              </View>

            </View>

            <View style={styles.task}>
              <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#FEF8E6", padding: 10, borderRadius: 13 }}>
                <Calendar height={35} width={25} fill={"#FCC626"} />

              </View>

              <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.blackTextInside}>Event</Text>
                <Text style={styles.grayText}>Create & Share Event</Text>
              </View>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NewScreen")}>
                <View>
                  <Add height={35} width={25} fill={"#ABA8BA"} />

                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
          </View>

          <Text style={styles.blackText}>Proposed classes</Text>

          {/* Proposed Class part */}
          <View style={{ padding: 30 }}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 20, padding: 10, elevation: 1, }}>
              <Text style={{ color: "#9993D3", fontSize: 18 }}>Math class</Text>
              <View style={styles.proposed}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#706E80", fontSize: 20 }}>Rasyid Hilman</Text>
                <View style={{ height: 35, width: 35, backgroundColor: "#FEE3AA", borderRadius: 25, marginHorizontal: 10, }} />

              </View>

              <View style={styles.proposed}>
                <View style={styles.agendaClockSvg}>
                  <Calendar height={40} width={30} fill={"#D4D3DA"} />
                  <Text style={{ color: "#B0AFB7", fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 10 }}>August 16, 2021</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.agendaClockSvg}>
                  <Clock height={40} width={30} fill={"#C0BFC6"} />
                  <Text style={{ color: "#AFAEB8", fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 10 }}>15:00</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>

        </ScrollView>

      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#FEFEFE",
  },
  appIcon: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: .5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#F7F6F9",
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  blackText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
  blackTextInside: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  grayText: {
    color: "#A29E97",
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  task: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 15,
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  proposed: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  agendaClockSvg: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  }


});

export default MainScreen;
```

Here is some part of the App screen,

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to store previous searches locally and then autocomplete based on your search history? If so, when do you want a search text to be saved? Because if you save a new string every time you add a letter to a word, it would be useless. First you need a mechanism to figure out when the user is done typing, like having a search button (or maybe you already have one, it's just really hard to find with that much code, if you can leave just the relevant parts for the text that would be great)

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting. Yes thats what I want to do, and you are right it would be useless if it saves everytime whenever i type a new letter. Well I want to control this by pressing enter. I mean while i am in textinput and i write  letter/word, and if i press on enter, it should save it, How could i do that?
could you also look at my other question if u dont mind? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716716/how-can-i-reach-my-function-globally-by-using-needed-thingscreatecontext-global

Comment: or as you said we can add a Search button, and we could use it.
or i dont know if it could be done but we may add onPress event for a textinput to do this, i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need `localStorage` to store your search list. Try to use below code. I couldn't run your whole code so I've created a small snippet which stores your search value on every onChange method. You can just move that to your handle click and get the value from localStorage on useState.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const [text, setText] = useState(localStorage.getItem("history") ? localStorage.getItem("history") : '');
    handleChange = (text) => {
      setText(text)
      localStorage.setItem("history", text)
    }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={{ flex: 1 }} placeholder="Search" onChangeText={handleChange} value={text}></TextInput>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Refer this link to read more about [Localstorage](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/)

Next time, It will be more better if you can create a snippet on [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/) and attach it here, So tht we can edit and help easily.